# After Windows 10 Update, ICloud no longer installs. Hangs at removing backup files

Tags: icloud

After Windows 10 Update, ICloud no longer installs. Hangs at removing backup files.  At this point, ICloud is installed and operating, but the windows installer hangs and requires a reboot if any install or uninstall is needed.  After a reboot, ICloud is automatically uninstalled.  I have tried all fixes recommended on the web, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I was told by a Microsoft technician that if your computer had Windows 10 installed as a virtual copy to your computer as opposed to having the physical install disc and installing from disc then the iCloud installation cannot remove the the backup files as they don't exist in reality, they only exist in the virtual copy of the program.  I may not be explaining this completely accurately but the jist is that if your original set up was from the factory where they used a "photo" copy of the program data to your hard disc in lieu of doing an actual install, then iCloud will always have problems.

Comment: Although a Microsoft technician gave you that explanation, it seems unlikely that his explanation is the correct answer.  Why would ICloud need to remove Windows 10 installation backup files?  I spoke at length with Microsoft and did not get that kind of answer..